# All Connectors go into Failed state after any connector deleted and recreated

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have SSL-enabled Kafka setup and registering messages on kafka-connect using POST request (below). If the connect setup is new with no existing connectors, it registers the connector fine. However, if I delete any connector, after sometime all connectors go into Failed state with TimeoutException (below). If I stop kafka-connect and delete all the metadata topics related to kafka-connect from kafka, and restart it. The problem goes but I have register all the connectors again. Problem is kafka-connect metadata topics not getting updated probably but I am not able to pin point the problem and find solution. 
Here is the POST request:

```
    curl -k -v -X POST -H "Accept:application/json"  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  https://kafka-connect.domain.com:9093/connectors/  -d '{
    "name": "TEST-CONNECTOR-TEST1131",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "test.domain.com",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.password": "test",
        "database.serverTimezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
        "database.server.id": "201908281131",
        "database.server.name": "TEST-CONNECTOR",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": 
        "kafka1.domain.com:9094",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.test_201908281131",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "table.whitelist": "qwerdb.test1",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
        "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.producer.ssl.key.password": "test",
        "database.history.producer.ssl.keystore.location": 
        "/opt/keystore.jks",
        "database.history.producer.ssl.keystore.password": "test",
        "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.location": 
        "/opt/truststore.jks",
        "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.password": "test"
    }
}'
```

This is the exception trace :

```
"trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata\n
\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:273)\n
\tat io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:47)\n
\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)\n
\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)\n
\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)\n
\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n
\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n
\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n
\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata\n"
```

Comment: Is it possible that database history bootstrap server was unavailable at time of restart?

Comment: @JiriPechanec This problem we are facing consistently, so it cannot be problem with database history bootstrap server not being available.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away after adding producer settings to kafka connect connect-distributed.properties file. These were missing from connect-distributed.properties file